# How can my GitHub repo have 1 visitor but 12 clones?

Tags: github

This has baffled me for quite a long time.

I notice that anyone with a link can download the repository. But the question is, where do they get the link from? I cannot seem to find a page on GitHub listing all the newly published repo.

Everytime I publish a new repo, there would be 3~6 mysterious clones follow shortly after, even when the number of visitor remains at most 2 persons.

While I welcome people to find out what my code can do, it somehow gives a pressure on me not to publish unfinalized code, and also not to amend the content of my repo after publishing it because they might already have cloned it before the changes are made.

Alright, it has 2 visitors (including me) to be exact:
[image: Traffic]

Comment: Are you using any CI or automated testing that runs on every push / commit? The program would clone each time to run a new build. Also, GitHub probably counts your own clones as well, and this likely also means one visitor can have many clones.

Comment: Hi @GoodDeeds, thank you for the response. No, I am not using any CI or automated testing, and I am not familiar with Git myself. Normally I upload the source files manually onto GitHub repo from Visual Studio project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no way to see who has checked out your repository using standard git commands such as `git clone`, but you can see who has forked your repository on GitHub in the Traffic section under Insights.

Now my first thought would be that those people cloned your repository outside of Github as you don't need to be a Github user to clone repository (so Github couldn't keep track of them and you wouldn't be able to see them).

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. There is no one forked my repository. Do you know of any sites which keep track of newly published GitHub repository?

Comment: I'm afraid I've never heard of such thing :/